# Get table2 data if it contains the primary key of table1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `COD_CLIENT` is the primary key of the `CLIENT` table. `Adress` has no primary key.

Table `CLIENT`:

```
COD_CLIENT | NAME_CLIENT
```

Table `ADRESS`:

```
COD_CLIENT | CITY | STREET | NUMBER
```

I want to get all the clients, and if an adress contains the client code, I want to select this row also, all in one query.

But if there is no adress, simply ignore the `Adress` row, but keep the `Client` data.

I tried this:

```
SELECT c.*,e.* 
FROM CLIENT c 
RIGHT JOIN ADRESS e (e.COD_CLIENT = c.COD_CLIENT)
```

But of course it didn't work.

How can I achieve those results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well... You only need to change your **Right Join** with a **Left Join** so SQL retrieves all the clients on clients table with their addresses. If they dont have addresses you'll get NULL in those fields.

SO:

```
SELECT c.*,e.* 
FROM CLIENT c 
LEFT JOIN ADRESS e ON e.COD_CLIENT = c.COD_CLIENT
```

REF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Sorry you miss the ON before "Adress e". So "SELECT c.*,e.* FROM CLIENT c LEFT JOIN ADRESS e ON (e.COD_CLIENT = c.COD_CLIENT)"

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the difference between RIGHT and LEFT join? Add to your answer if possible

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - perhaps this link will help you understand the difference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/597030?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*,e.* 
FROM CLIENT c 
LEFT JOIN ADRESS e ON e.COD_CLIENT = c.COD_CLIENT
```